# How to avoid math.sin(math.pi*2*VERY LARGE NUMBER) having a much larger error margin than math.sin(math.pi*2)?

Tags: python, numpy, math, precision, trigonometry

I've read in other questions that that for example sin(2π) is not zero due to floating point representation, but is very close. This very small error is no issue in my code as I can just round up 5 decimals for example.

However when multiplying 2π with a very large number, the error is magnified a lot. The answer should be zero (or close), but is far from it.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in my thinking? If not, how can I avoid the error margin of floating numbers for π to get "magnified" as the number of periods (2*PI*X) → ∞ ?

Notice that all the 3 last results are the same. Can anyone explain why this is even though 5) is exactly PI/2 larger than 4)? Even with a huge offset in the sinus curve, an increase in PI/2 should still produce a different number right?

1. Checking small number SIN(2*PI)

   ```
   print math.sin(math.pi*2)
   ```

   RESULT = -2.44929359829e-16 AS EXPECTED → This error margin is OK for my purpose
2. Adding PI/2 to code above: SIN(2*PI + PI/2)

   ```
   print math.sin((math.pi*2)+(math.pi/2))
   ```

   RESULT: 1.0 AS EXPECTED
3. Checking very large number SIN(2*PI*VERY LARGE NUMBER) (still expecting close to zero)

   ```
   print math.sin(math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751))
   ```

   RESULT:-0.759488037749 NOT AS EXPECTED --> This error margin is NOT OK for my purpose
4. Adding PI/2 to code above: SIN(2*PI*VERY LARGE NUMBER + PI/2) (expecting close to one)

   ```
   print math.sin((math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751))+(math.pi/2))
   ```

   As above but I added PI/2 - expecting to get 1.0 as result
   RESULT:-0.759488037749 NOT AS EXPECTED - why the same result as above when I added PI/2 (should go a quarter period on the sinus curve)
5. Adding random number (8) to the very large number, expecting neither 1 nor 0

   ```
   print math.sin(math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993759))
   ```

   as above but I added 8 - expecting to get neither 0 nor 1
   RESULT:-0.759488037749 NOT AS EXPECTED - why the same result as above when I added 8

Comment: Why are you *"expecting to get neither 0 nor 1"* for 5)? The mathematically correct result is 0.

Comment: Oops, you are correct - what I meant was doing a +8 to the whole parentheses within sin(x+8) -> just to shift it to a random place on the sinus curve. Sorry!

Comment: @Harry You want the function `sinpi()`, which computes sin(πx) accurately even for x large in magnitude, by performing the multiplication with π internally, after argument reduction. E.g. `scipy.special.sinpi` or `mpmath.sinpi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply isn't going to work with double-precision variables.

The value of `math.pi` is correct only to about 16 places of decimals (53 bits in binary), so when you multiply it by a number like 415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751 (159 bits), it would be impossible to get meaningful results.

You need to use an arbitrary precision math library instead. Try using [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org) for example. Tell it you want 1000 bits of precision, and then try your sums again:

```py
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.mp.prec=1000
>>> print(mpmath.sin((mpmath.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751))+(mpmath.pi/2)))
1.0
```

Comment: You should really not use `import *` ... This is an excellent answer but only because the `pi` you are using here is not the `math.pi` in other answers. That tripped me up (but maybe that was just me.)

Comment: Thank you! This works! My specific code is still showing errors, but I'm much closer to the results at least!

Comment: Good point. I'll edit the answer to clarify. It might also help if I added a link to the documentation on the  [basic usage of mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.1.0/basics.html).

Comment: Why should I not use "import *"?

Comment: Follow the link in my last comment; it explains what happens.

Comment: Thanks! Using mpmath works great with pi for many decimal points - another issue I see: Why is this code below not giving me many decimal points on all prints - only with PI? ‘import math
from mpmath import *
mp.prec=1000

x = 5431526412865007456
print mpf((x)/6)

ACTUAL OUTPUT: 905254402144167909.0
CORRECT OUTPUT: 905254402144167909.3333333333333333333333(…)’

Comment: How about using `mpmath` to reduce the angle mod (2 * pi) so that it's between 0 and (2 * pi), and then use the math.sin on the result? I don't think OP needs 1000 bits of precision in the sin *result*.

Comment: @Harry Change `x = 5431526412865007456` to `x = mpf(5431526412865007456)`. And please read the mpmath documentation.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Use whatever precision you like. But if you want to reduce a 159-bit number to a number between 0 and 2π to get a result with 53 bits of precision, you'll need to use at least 212 bits of precision.

Answer (score 2):

> How to avoid `math.sin(math.pi*2*VERY LARGE NUMBER)` having a much larger error margin than `math.sin(math.pi*2)`?

You could `% 1` that very large number:

```
>>> math.sin(math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751))
-0.8975818793257183
>>> math.sin(math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751 % 1))
0.0
```

```
>>> math.sin((math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751))+(math.pi/2))
-0.8975818793257183
>>> math.sin((math.pi*2*(415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751 % 1))+(math.pi/2))
1.0
```

Comment: But `that_large_number % 1 = 0`. So you are only printing that `sin(math.pi/2) = 1`.

Comment: @usr2564301 I know.

Comment: Yes, I need the specific value of the large number to still be the same into the calculation. What I showed here is a simplification of my algorithm, so just setting the large number to zero will not work.

Comment: @Harry Not sure what you mean. I'm only "setting it to zero" for the purpose of multiplying it with `pi*2` in the context of `sin`, where that's correct. I'm not destroying your number. And it's only "setting to zero" for integers. For example `2.718 % 1` gives you `0.718`.

Comment: @HeapOverflow But 415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751.12345 % 1 == 0.0

Comment: @r3mainer That's an earlier problem, though. The number represented by `415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751.12345` is already an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms used are approximate, and the values (e.g. pi) are approximate. So $\pi \cdot {SomeLargeNumber}$ *will* have a largeish error (as $\pi$'s value is approximate). The function used (by hardware?) will reduce the argument, perhaps using a slightly different value of $\pi$.

Note that floating point arithmetic **does not** satisfy the axioms for real arithmetic.

Comment: Thank for your answer. As you can see, stackoverflow does not support any TeX-like markup. You may of course leave your answer as is, but I think it would look better without the '$' and '\' in them.

Comment: Yes, but this site does not, and your answer is on this site.